# NoSuchElementFoundExeption in android native app

Tags: java, selenium, appium

**Appium version 1.12.1**, 
**windows 10**, 
working **platform=android version 5.1.1**, **4.4**, **6.0**
Not working in **android version 7.1** and above

I am getting `NoSuchElementFoundExeption` error continuously during following scenario in android app

Before loading the page there is RestAPI call requesting data from server during this a `progressDailogue` is shown, so once after 
page loaded it shows the data with native components(`TextView`, `Buttons` etc) and the `progressDailogue` hides.

Once the native elements are displayed I am trying to click on the element by using ID(tried by xpath) but it is showing `NoSuchElementFoundExeption` also I tried by using wait method and adding some delay still it is displaying the same error.

I tried by removing the process dailog box in my app where it works fine, But I wanted to find the element and click on the element without removing the process dailog box.

This is sample code tried

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
element.click();
```

How to get the elements click working after hiding `progressDailogue`.

So any help on this?

15/05/2019

Not able access any element from that particular page, 
here I am trying to click on the element by using ID=plans_proceed_btn_child

page source

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><hierarchy rotation="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1184]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,1184]" resource-id="" instance="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][720,1184]" resource-id="" instance="1"><android.view.ViewGroup index="0" text="" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][720,1184]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/decor_content_parent" instance="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][720,160]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/action_bar_container" instance="2"><android.view.ViewGroup index="0" text="" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][720,160]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/action_bar" instance="1"><android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[286,48][434,160]" resource-id="" instance="1"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Subscribe" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[286,85][434,123]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/actionbarTitle" instance="0"/></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.view.ViewGroup></android.widget.FrameLayout><android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,160][720,1184]" resource-id="android:id/content" instance="3"><android.view.ViewGroup index="0" text="" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,160][720,1184]" resource-id="" instance="2"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,160][720,1184]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_root_parent" instance="0"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,160][720,390]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_tv_parent" instance="1"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="How many products would you like to display in your product catalogue ?" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,180][700,336]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_tv" instance="1"/><android.widget.TextView index="1" text="Price will be updated based on your selection" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,336][700,370]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_caption_tv" instance="2"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,410][720,630]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_details_viewpager_parent" instance="2"><android.support.v4.view.ViewPager index="0" text="" class="android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,410][720,630]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_viewpager" instance="0"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[160,410][560,630]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/planCardView" instance="4"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[192,458][528,579]" resource-id="" instance="5"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[192,458][528,579]" resource-id="" instance="3"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Upto 200 Products" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[212,478][508,559]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plan_display_name_tv" instance="3"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout><android.widget.FrameLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[560,410][720,630]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/planCardView" instance="6"><android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[592,458][720,579]" resource-id="" instance="7"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[592,458][720,579]" resource-id="" instance="4"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Upto 500 Products" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[612,478][720,559]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plan_display_name_tv" instance="4"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.ScrollView index="2" text="" class="android.widget.ScrollView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,630][720,1030]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/scroll_feature_plan_parent" instance="0"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,650][700,1030]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/features_layout_parent" instance="5"><android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,670][680,1030]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_feature_parent_layout" instance="2"><android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,670][680,766]" resource-id="" instance="3"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Have your own Digital Address" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,670][359,766]" resource-id="" instance="5"/><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[359,670][360,766]" resource-id="" instance="0"/><android.widget.TextView index="2" text="yourcompanyname.abc.com" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[360,670][680,766]" resource-id="" instance="6"/></android.widget.LinearLayout><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,766][680,767]" resource-id="" instance="1"/><android.widget.LinearLayout index="2" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,767][680,863]" resource-id="" instance="4"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Add Team members up to" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,767][359,863]" resource-id="" instance="7"/><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[359,767][360,863]" resource-id="" instance="2"/><android.widget.TextView index="2" text="10" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[360,784][680,845]" resource-id="" instance="8"/></android.widget.LinearLayout><android.view.View index="3" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,863][680,864]" resource-id="" instance="3"/><android.widget.LinearLayout index="4" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,864][680,960]" resource-id="" instance="5"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Invite buyers to your Digital Store" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,864][359,960]" resource-id="" instance="9"/><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[359,864][360,960]" resource-id="" instance="4"/><android.widget.ImageView index="2" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[360,878][680,946]" resource-id="" instance="0"/></android.widget.LinearLayout><android.view.View index="5" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,960][680,961]" resource-id="" instance="5"/><android.widget.LinearLayout index="6" text="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,961][680,1030]" resource-id="" instance="6"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Announce offers and updates to your customers" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[40,961][359,1030]" resource-id="" instance="10"/><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[359,961][360,1030]" resource-id="" instance="6"/><android.widget.ImageView index="2" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[360,992][680,1030]" resource-id="" instance="1"/></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.ScrollView><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="3" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,959][720,1017]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plan_switch_parent" instance="6"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="6-Months" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[159,959][299,1011]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/planName_a_tv" instance="11"/><android.widget.Switch index="1" text="ON" class="android.widget.Switch" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="true" checked="true" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[299,959][413,1017]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plan_switch_btn" instance="0"/><android.widget.TextView index="2" text="12-Months" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[413,959][561,1011]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/planName_b_tv" instance="12"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="4" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1057][720,1184]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_proceed_btn_parent" instance="7"><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="0" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,1077][202,1164]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_amount_parent" instance="8"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="?16,620" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,1077][193,1136]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_amount_tv" instance="13"/><android.widget.TextView index="1" text="(taxes applicable)" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[20,1136][202,1164]" resource-id="" instance="14"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="1" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[516,1077][700,1158]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_proceed_btn_child" instance="9"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Pay" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[536,1077][632,1158]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/plans_proceed_btn" instance="15"/><android.widget.ImageView index="1" text="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[632,1093][680,1141]" resource-id="" instance="2"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout><android.widget.RelativeLayout index="5" text="" class="android.widget.RelativeLayout" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1070][720,1108]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/see_more_features_parent" instance="10"><android.widget.TextView index="0" text="Show all" class="android.widget.TextView" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1070][720,1108]" resource-id="com.abc.abcpp:id/see_more_features_tv" instance="16"/></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.widget.RelativeLayout></android.view.ViewGroup></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.view.ViewGroup></android.widget.FrameLayout></android.widget.LinearLayout><android.view.View index="1" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][720,48]" resource-id="android:id/statusBarBackground" instance="7"/><android.view.View index="2" text="" class="android.view.View" package="com.abc.abcpp" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1184][720,1280]" resource-id="android:id/navigationBarBackground" instance="8"/></android.widget.FrameLayout></hierarchy>.
```

Comment: What is `element` ? Can you share that element ?

Comment: This code won't cause `NoSuchElementFoundExeption`. Post the relevant code and html.

Comment: I have updated relevent html code above and shared Id for the element.